# Angular JS ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I Followed that link to learn how to use: ng-include: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_includes.asp

But I Have few questions and I not understand well how it works.

If I remove app1.js = the ng include will not works, why? I really not understand angular I am just trying for the first time.

app1.js

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('userCtrl', function($scope) {

})
```

as well if I am not running this code in a server will not works too, why?

html code:

```
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script> 

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="userCtrl">

<div class="container">
  <div ng-include="'includes/content.html'"></div>
  <div ng-include="'includes/header.html'"></div>
</div>

<script src= "js/app1.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When you are removing app1.js are you also dropping the ng-app and ng-controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use the `<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="userCtrl">`

After you remove the `app1.js` there is no `controller` to match with the `ng-controller` so there will be a error saying `undefined` controller (check the console),

and change the `ng-app="myApp"` to `ng-app`, if you keep the `ng-app="myApp"` then it will search for a module called `myApp` as `angular.module('myApp', [])`

remove the `ng-controller` directive and check it will work.

then whole think would be

```
<body ng-app>...
```

Comment: i did and i got this error: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)

Comment: you should also remove `ng-app="myApp"` and just leave `ng-app`, because when you remove `app.js`, a reference to `myApp` is also removed.

Comment: oh yeas remove as @Jahongir said ill update the answer thanks for pointing it out :)